# How to set Rails.env to development when starting server with redis

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redis

I know that I could do

> RAILS_ENV=production rails s

However, I have an existing application which I need to maintain. I can't find anywhere in the deployment script that seem to directly start rails server. I suspect that this line below which starts redis-server would bring up rails.

> nohup sudo service redis-server start some_path/config/redis.conf &

Can someone please confirm this is how rails server gets started in my app?

Also, when I check the server, Rails.env is "production", but I need it to be "development" for my staging/test server. How can I configure this so that rails server is started in development mode instead of production mode? Thanks!

Edit:
I fount that rails env is actually specified in /opt/nginx/conf/nginx.conf. After changing from

> rails_env production;

to

> rails_env development;

It works.

Comment: See the documentation for your shell / OS for how to set ENV vars.  Or you can use [dotenv](https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv) or [direnv](https://direnv.net/).

Comment: Also you should NOT run a server in development mode unless it is on your local machine or in a closed network. Running rails with the default development settings is not considered safe on a public facing server. You will get hacked. Instead create a separate environment and base the settings off `config/environments/production.rb`

Comment: @max Thanks for your comment. My test/staging server is running in a closed network so I guess we are not at risk of getting hacked. However, I am interested in learning more on what you said. Many places in the app I check for Rails.env to decide whether to perform some action that should only be performed on production servers. On non-prod servers, I'll display a message back to client that "This operation is not allowed on staging server". If I don't do the prod vs non-prod detection based on Rails.env, how else could I do it?

Comment: You do it with `Rails.env`. But `Rails.env` is really just a clever string, you can add however many environments you want. I often use public staging servers - you just create a `config/environments/staging.rb` file and set `RAILS_ENV=staging`. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#creating-rails-environments

Comment: `Rails.env` even uses some metaprogramming magic so you can do `Rails.env.foo?` or whatever you want and it will only return true if that matches `ENV["RAILS_ENV"]`

Comment: Thanks guys, appreciate your help!